# How to create a file, insert string to file and set it's permissions in kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, permissions, manifest, createfile

For some reason, I am unable to do this in the docker file when creating the docker image.  I think it's because of the VOLUME statement. Some suggested to run the VOLUME statement before the creation of the file and setting the permissions but it doesn't matter what order it's done in, it just doesn't work.

So I am left with trying to use the model file to create the file, insert the data and set the permissions.  I've tried to many combinations but none of it works.  I don't know this stuff very well so would appreciate any ideas.

What commands can I use in the below code to create a file, add a key to it and then set permissions like chmod 600?

Here's the code:

```
containers:
    mongo:
      image: mongo
      imageVersion: 3.0.4

      lifecycle:
        command:
          - mongod
        args:
          - --config
          - /etc/mongo/mongod.conf
      services:
        - port: 27017
          nodePort: ${{ vars.nodePorts["mongo_" + subnames[1] + "_" + location] }}

      volumeMappingSet:
        - PERSISTED:/data/db

      resources:
        cpu: tiny
        memory: tiny
```

Here's the docker file code:

```
RUN mkdir -p /ls -lrt data/db /data/configdb && \
    chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db /data/configdb

USER mongodb:mongodb

RUN  touch /data/db/replica.key && \
  echo -e 'key'\
      >> /data/db/replica.key && \
      chown mongodb:mongodb /data/db/replica.key && \
      chgrp mongodb /data/db/replica.key && \
      chmod 600 /data/db/replica.key

VOLUME /data/db /data/configdb
EXPOSE 27017

CMD ["mongod"]
```

Comment: What tool processes this YAML file?  It looks neither like a Kubernetes manifest nor like a Docker Compose file.  What sort of file are you trying to create and where should it go?

Comment: Could you use k8s lifecycles and a postStart command : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/#define-poststart-and-prestop-handlers ?

Comment: so this file is processed by a jenkins job and it creates a number of deployment files which are also in a yaml format

Comment: I'll add my dockerfile code which also seems to not work

Comment: I've tried the lifecycles poststart by I get an error from this when the jenkins jobs runs.  May be some issue with our own in house code